# No se puede actualizar este recordset MS Access

Tags: mysql, ms-access

Tengo dos tablas vinculadas, una en MS Access en local y la otra una MySQL en un servidor. Llamémosle `pedidos` a ambas. El caso es que estaba actualizando un campo en MS Access, y me salió el error de "conflicto de escritura: el registro ha sido modificado por otro usuario". Probé varias cosas, pero al no tener solución, reinicié el ordenador. Tras el reinicio, ahora directamente no me deja escribir en la tabla de MS Access, me dice que no se puede actualizar este recordset. He estado mirando varias cosas pero no sé qué hacer para que funcione y me deje escribir y actualizar los datos de MySQL desde la tabla de MSAccess. ¿Alguna idea? Gracias.

Comment: ¿Ejecutas la consulta desde Access directamente o desde otra parte? ¿El usuario tiene permisos sobre esa BD?

Comment: Desde Access, simplemente estoy intentando escribir información en un campo.

Comment: ¿Esa BD está enlazada (linked) con otra de algún modo?

Comment: En [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13993410/5587982) se recogen los tres motivos principales por los que esto puede ocurrir. Verifica, según tu contexto.

Comment: La BD está enlazada a otra MySQL. Pudiera ser por los NULL, quizás.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probablemente el problema venga de que la base de datos Access se ha abierto y no se ha cerrado correctamente. Si lo hace alguna aplicación el problema radica en que esta no ha cerrado la conexión, dejando bloqueada la tabla. [Aquí tienes documentación](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/office/troubleshoot/access/lock-files-introduction)

La base de datos crea un archivo de bloqueo, dependiendo de la versión del fichero se llamará exactamente igual pero con la extensión .accdb o .ldb.

Sólo tienes que eliminar este fichero y revisar quien o que abre la conexión pero no la cierra para que no vuelva a ocurrir.

Comment: A ver el problema es el siguiente:

-Esta mañana, al principio, me dejaba editar y actualizar. Le dí a actualizar por primera vez y la información aparecía en MySQL.
-Posteriormente, sigo intentando actualizar, y ya no me dejaba.
-He borrado el archivo de bloqueo, y leído la documentación, pero sigue sin funcionar y sin ni idea de qué puedo hacer. ¿Alguna idea? Gracias.

P.D. Cambiando datos en MySQL sí se me actualizan simultáneamente en MS Access, pero no al revés.

Answer (score 0):

me ha pasado exactamente lo mismo. Era capaz de editar registros en un formulario que obtenía datos directamente de MySQL y en unos minutos salía el mensaje de "no-se-puede-actualizar-este-recordset-ms-access". Además, el diseño del formulario es igual al de otro que sí funciona con otra de las tablas vinculadas de MySQL. Al final he optado por eliminar los vínculos a las tablas y volver a crearlos y ya funciona.